Why is the Cache-Control header not coming through while it is set in google cloud console?
I'm working on a project with NextJS and Firebase where I'll be using lots of images on a website. I'd like to Browser Cache these images to reduce the amount of requests sent to Firebase Storage. To test this I've added 1 single image in Firebase Storage. I then used Google Cloud Console to manually add "public,max-age=86400" in the Cache-Controle header.
GSC bucket
GSC image meta data
Then when I look up the meta data of the image in GSC I can see that the header is set correctly. But whenever I load the page and check the response headers in the dev tools it states that the Cache-Control value is "public, max-age=60, must-revalidate"
dev tools network tab
I've tried clearing my cache in the browser and reloading the page for every of the below points:

tested on localhost & by deploying to production, same results
Adding a space in the header value: "public, max-age=86400"
Changing the order of the header value: "max-age=86400,public" & with space "max-age=86400, public"
Adding the below config in next.config.mjs

images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'firebasestorage.googleapis.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/v0/b/**',
      },
    ],
    minimumCacheTTL: 86400,
  }

None, worked and I don't really now where to go from here. I've reviewed other questions, but they get some results or are about Firebase Functions. Any help is appreciated! :)
